# MeteorJS Publish Subscribe

Tags: node.js, meteor

**ЧТО Я ХОЧУ СДЕЛАТЬ :** К примеру у меня есть сайт который публикует новости взятые из Mongo в ввиде списка `<ul><li>...`

```
<ul>
   {{#each posts}}
     {{> post}}
   {{/each}}
</ul>

Template.table.helpers({
  posts: function(){
     return Posts.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }} );
   }
})
```

И у меня есть в навигации 2 ссылки "Новые посты" и "Лучшие посты". Они оба ипользуют один template, но по содержанию они отличаются тем, что одни посты публикуются с параметром

```
best: true
```

а вторые с парметром `new:true` так как я использую один template то мне возращаются посты с чем то одним `return Posts.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }} );` в хелпере.

**ВОПРОС :** Каким образом можно сделать 2 одинаковых данных, но с разными параметрами на 1 темплейте.

Пробывал через iron router + public/subscribe, не вышло

```
Meteor.publish('new', function(){
    return Posts.find({fields:{new:true}},{ sort: { createdAt: -1 }});
});
Meteor.publish('best', function(){
    return Posts.find({fields:{best:true}},{ sort: { createdAt: -1 }});
});

newPostsController= RouteController.extend({
    template: 'timeTable',
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('new');
    }
});

bestPostController= newPostsController.extend({
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('best');
  }
});


Router.map(function() {

  this.route('new', {
        path: '/new',
        controller: newPostsController
    });

  this.route('best', {
      path: '/best',
      controller: bestPostController
  });
});
```

Есть другие варианты ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

У Вас ничего не получилось так как *waitOn*, в отличии от того же *action* или *data*, при расширении контроллера не перезаписывается. [Он работает по принципу схожему к хуку.](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/b37edb76073ee2f5a8df4cb3004cec92128cf4ed/lib/router.js#L347) То есть *bestPostController* не затрет *waitOn* от *newPostsController*, а про100 дополнит его. В результате у Вас будет две подписки на роутере *best*.

**Как решить проблему**
1) Создайте базовый контроллер *postsController*
2) Определите в *postsController* общие данные для всех последующих контроллеров
3) Создайте контроллеры *bestPostController* и *newPostsController*, которые будут расширять функционал *postsController*

**Как это выглядит в коде**

```
postsController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'timeTable'
  // Другие общие данные
});

newPostsController = postsController.extend({
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('new');
  }
});

bestPostController = postsController.extend({
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('best');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

2 контроллера - это хорошо, но не всем может подойти. Кому-то нужен именно фильтр документов коллекции, для этого можно воспользоваться реактивными переменными и зависимостями.

Сначала в роуте нужно убрать `waitOn`.

Затем в публикации:

```
Meteor.publish("posts", function(options){
  var query = {};
  options = options || {};
  if(options.new)
    query.new = true;
  if(options.best)
    query.best = true;

  posts = Posts.find(query);
  return posts;
});
```

В *posts.html*:

```
<template name="posts">
<input type="checkbox" class="best"/> Лучшие посты<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="new"/> Новые посты
<br>
<ul>
   {{#each posts}}
     {{> post}}
   {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

В шаблоне *posts.js*:

```
PostsFilter = {
  get: function() {
    if(!this.dep)
      this.dep = new Deps.Dependency();
    this.dep.depend();
    if(this.filter)
      return this.filter;
  },
  set: function(new, best) {
    var changed = false;
    if((new === true || new === false) && this.filter.new != new)
    {
      this.filter.new = new;
      changed = true;
    }
    if((best === true || best === false) && this.filter.best != best)
    {
      this.filter.best = best;
      changed = true;
    }
    if(changed) this.dep.changed();
  }
};

Deps.autorun(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe("posts", PostsFilter.get());
});

Template.posts.events({
  'click .new': function(e) {
    if($(e.target).prop("checked"))
      PostsFilter.set(true);
    else
      PostsFilter.set(false);
  },
  'click .best': function() {
    if($(e.target).prop("checked"))
      PostsFilter.set(null, true);
    else
      PostsFilter.set(null, false);
  }
});
```